# Any component for displaying the file-system / file-tree in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, shell, firemonkey

Couldn't find any file-tree component (cross-platform, of course) in the FireMonkey framework.  Anyone has any idea or knows such a component?  Sounds like a basic thing to me.

I'm looking for a simple "explorer-like" tree view, not really important if it's really pretty as I can probably restyle it or inherit and change.  Ideas?...

Comment: you'll have to wait for that, I haven't seen, read or heard about such a comoonent, xe2 is not very mature, so either give it some time, or create your own...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's **no component** (out of the box) but you can quickly implement it using the unit **System.IOUtils** which is working on all platforms.

For instance, to give you an idea:

```
uses
  System.IOUtils, FMX.TreeView, ...

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    tvPath: TTreeView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
...

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  sRoot    : string;
  sdaDrives: TStringDynArray;
  sDrive   : string;
  tviDrive : TTreeViewItem;
  osv      : TOSVersion;
begin
  if TOSVersion.Platform = pfMacOS then
  begin
    // Root's folders
    sRoot     := '/';
    sdaDrives := TDirectory.GetDirectories(sRoot);
    for sDrive in sdaDrives do
    begin
      tviDrive      := TTreeViewItem.Create(Self);
      tviDrive.Text := sDrive;
      tvPath.AddObject(tviDrive);
    end;
    sdaDrives := TDirectory.GetFiles(sRoot);
  end
  else
  begin
    // Root's folders
    sRoot     := TDirectory.GetDirectoryRoot(ParamStr(0)); // you probably want to use TDirectory.GetLogicalDrives before this one...
    sdaDrives := TDirectory.GetDirectories(sRoot);
    for sDrive in sdaDrives do
    begin
      tviDrive      := TTreeViewItem.Create(Self);
      tviDrive.Text := sDrive;
      tvPath.AddObject(tviDrive);
    end;
    sdaDrives := TDirectory.GetFiles(sRoot);
  end;
  // files
  for sDrive in sdaDrives do
  begin
    tviDrive            := TTreeViewItem.Create(Self);
    tviDrive.Text       := ExtractFileName(sDrive);
    tviDrive.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsItalic];
    tvPath.AddObject(tviDrive);
  end;
end;
```

This is just a proof of concept, as it works on both platform.. of course, there's still some work to do...
I have used System.SysUtils.TOSVersion to show you another record which can maybe be also useful...

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Will wait on a few more comments, and if none will mark as Best Answer.

Comment: There's no rush.. take your time :)